# WSDL / Web Service and need to generate interfaces

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I have an WSDL / Web Service and I need to generate an set of Interfaces for them, is there any easy way of generating Interfaces for the WSDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're a C# developer I'm assuming you mean C# interfaces for the client? You can do this using [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for WCF or [WSDL.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) for legacy Web services.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Download [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for free.  SoapUI can [generate code, interfaces, or stubs](http://www.soapui.org/userguide/tools/topdown.html) for a variety of platforms, including .NET and numerous Java formats.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) has tools that will generate interfaces for several languages